# In spring mvc boot can't connect to mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring project, when I try to connect to mysql the terminal doesn't tell me failed but tell me everything is good but not connection, I will show you terminal message, pom.xml, applaction.properties  below.

Notes: I did not leave any site or video that I did not watch and did not find a solution to this problem

terminal message and application.properties.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IavRJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IavRJ.png)

pom.xml

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it tell you everything is good because in the definition of dependency for mysql you don't precise is runtime as you know The dependencies with this scope are required at runtime then add this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.28</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

and try again